# RedirectMatch: redirects to wrong URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I switched a Shop-CMS and put a lot of old URL into the .htaccess to redirect old products to their new location.

But some redirects are wrong:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/catxy/313? https://www.example.com/products/catxy/product-1/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/catxy/314? https://www.example.com/products/catxy/product-2/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/catxy/319? https://www.example.com/products/catxy/product-3/
```

When I go to example.com/products/catxy/319 I get redirected to product-1 and not to product-3

As I understand the regex above it means starting with /products/catxy/319[MAYBEMORE] -> redirect to product-3

I can't write ^/products/catxy/319$ because there are a lot of different endings for 319 (all variations of that product id).

I don't know either if it would be better to use mod_rewrite in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is presence of `?` in the end of pattern: `^/products/catxy/313?`, which is making last digit optional so your first rule matches anything that starts with:

```
/products/catxy/313
```

or

```
products/catxy/31
```

You probably means to keep trailing slash optional and have your rules like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/catxy/313(?:/.*)?$ https://www.example.com/products/catxy/product-1/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/catxy/314(?:/.*)?$ https://www.example.com/products/catxy/product-2/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/catxy/319(?:/.*)?$ https://www.example.com/products/catxy/product-3/
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing the changes.

Comment: No that didn't worked … but with you answer I changed it to ^/products/catxy/319(.*)$ and this is working in my case

Comment: Check it now, it should work. Your URL probably has more text after `313`